# Webpack: Compilation error when going through the Getting Started tutorial

Tags: javascript, webpack

Getting a compilation error when following the Webpack tutorial at https://webpack.js.org/guides/getting-started/.

I've gone through it three times now, one time where I typed everything in manually to avoid any hidden characters from copy-paste.

Running on Powershell on Windows 10, Npm version 8.3.0, Lodash version 4.17.21, Webpack version 5.66.0, Webpack-cli version 4.9.1.

The error message is this:

```
(base) PS C:\path\to\webpack-demo> npx webpack
assets by status 291 bytes [cached] 1 asset
./src/index.js 458 bytes [built] [code generated] [1 error]

WARNING in configuration
The 'mode' option has not been set, webpack will fallback to 'production' for this value.
Set 'mode' option to 'development' or 'production' to enable defaults for each environment.
You can also set it to 'none' to disable any default behavior. Learn more: https://webpack.
js.org/configuration/mode/

ERROR in ./src/index.js 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are confi
gured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
(Source code omitted for this binary file)

webpack 5.66.0 compiled with 1 error and 1 warning in 196 ms
```

I'll paste in the lines of code I have here, but they should be identical to what's in the tutorial.

`index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="uft-8" />
    <title>Getting Started </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

`index.js`:

```
import _ from 'lodash';

function component {
  const element = document.createElement('div');

  element.innerHTML = _.join(['Hello', 'webpack'], ' ');

  return element;
}

document.body.appendChild(component());
```

`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "webpack-demo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^5.66.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "lodash": "^4.17.21"
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm sure you saw in your error message the error about `ERROR in ./src/index.js 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:0)`...it looks like whatever you're using for an editor is adding hidden/special characters of some sort. You might need to delete that file and recreate it, and be sure to do it with a "pure" text editor.

Comment: @David784 Hey, yes, that was why I mentioned that I tried typing it in manually on the third attempt at going through the tutorial. I edit in Neovim, so I'd be surprised if that was the problem.